# Another user has left a localhost connection running I cannot stop

Tags: mysql, localhost, mamp

Forgive my vague wording on this (it is not my strong point).

Basically I am trying to run a site locally so in MACS host file I have set the URL to run locally and set the site up on MAMP.

This issue I am having is another user on this pc has left a connection running so when i look at any site locally it shows there site not mine.

They no longer work here so we do not have the password to access there account.

Is there a way to turn this off or overwrite this.

Once again

Sorry for vagueness

Thanks for any potential help in advanced.

David

Comment: Depends on what they're running. Could be native Apache, or another Apache (like homebrew's version), could be running PHP's built in server... You could try and restart the machine but they may be using a launch daemon to restart it each time.  If that's the case you'd need to kill that off.

Comment: you could try running `lsof -Pn -i4` in terminal. This will tell you what files are open including network sockets. You might be able to determine from that what what is listening on your localhost.